# Maven - Unsupported driver type: CHROMEDRIVER.EXE

Tags: maven

I am running Serenity test case using the Maven from command prompt using "MVN Clean Install". But my test is failing when I use chrome browser with the below message. Same is working if I use the FIREFOX browser.

> net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Unsupported browser type: chromedriver.exe. Did you mean firefox?
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported driver type: CHROMEDRIVER.EXE

---

My Chrome browser version is 76 and chrome driver is 75.

### Same is working fine if i run the case from Eclipse IDE.

My POM.XML is having the below tag under Properties

```
<webdriver.driver>chromedriver.exe</webdriver.driver>
```

Serenity properties files has the below code

```
# Define the default driver

webdriver.driver=chrome
webdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved when I do the below changes.

```html
<webdriver.driver>chrome</webdriver.driver>
```